# Regex, getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I call findElements when window.onLoad, with HTML code, 
 tmp2 selects all tags but the others don't. I really cannot figure out; thanks in advance.

```
function findElements(){
    var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName("*"); // nothing
    var tmp2 = document.getElementsByTagName("*");  // all tags, so regexp could be input arg.
    var tmp3 = document.getElementsByTagName("b..."); // nothing, but body tag is supposed to be selected
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName` method **does not accept regular expressions** as arguments.

It accepts only **strings** which must either be:

- The wild card `*`
- An exact match for the element type

The `getElementsByClassName` method **does not accept regular expressions**.

It accepts only **strings** which must be:

- An exact match for the class name

---

The `querySelectorAll` method can use [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) to make more complex matching of attributes (including the class attribute), but even it does not support regular expressions.

---

If you really want to do a regular expression match, the you would need to select all elements with the wild card (`getElementsByTagName("*")`) and then loop over the results, testing each one in turn.